# Why does the following python script not copy the files as expected?

Tags: python, loops, path, copy, shutil

At the beginning, someone tried to copy a whole harddrive to another place. There were a lot of errors copying some files, whose new path would have exceeded the max. path length. I got all those affected files in a folder, my task is to now copy them to the place they belong.

This is how I do it:

1. Create a dictionary paths.
2. Set a key in this dictionary for every file to copy as its source path
3. Read a Excelfile, which includes the destination path and assign it as a value to the corresponding key
4. Manipulate the filename by adding a "_mig" between filename and file extension, so I can see in the destination that this was copied by myself and not originally there.

This is - more or less - what happens in the "setOldPath()" and "setNewPath()" functions.
Everything comes together in the following main function, that uses the paths-dictionary to copy the files:

```
def main():
setOldPath(Path(input("Please paste the source path in here:\n")))
setNewPath(r"\\fe24999\C_CCH_GLW$\40_IT\Projekt_Digitales_Archiv_CS\DLZA-Bosch\Charlie 2020\Masseningest Dais-Ablage\Auswertung MIG-Ordner\2020-08-26_Auswertung-MIG-Ordner.xlsx")
countSuccess = 0
countAll = 0
Errorlog = open("allErrors.log", "w", encoding="utf-8")
Correctlog = open("allCopied.log", "w", encoding="utf-8")

for current, new in paths.items():
    try:
        base, extension = os.path.splitext(new)
        test = os.path.exists(new)
        print(test)
        if not os.path.exists(new):     
            shutil.copy(current, winapi_path(new))
            print("first time")
        else:
            print("more times")
            i = 1
            while os.path.exists(os.path.join(new, '{}{}{}'.format(base, i, extension))):
                i += 1
            new= os.path.join(new, '{}{}{}'.format(base, i, extension))
            print(new)
            shutil.copy(current, winapi_path(new))
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nError with %s" % (current))
        Errorlog.write("Error: %s \n could not copy %s \nto \n%s \n\n" % (e, current, new))
        countAll += 1
    else:
        print("\nSuccessfully COPIED")
        Correctlog.write("Successfully copied %s \nto \n%s \n\n" % (current,new))
        countSuccess += 1
        countAll += 1
Errorlog.write("%d out of %d Elements successfully processed." % (countSuccess, countAll))
Errorlog.close()
Correctlog.write("%d out of %d Elements successfully processed." % (countSuccess, countAll))
Correctlog.close()
print("\n%d out of %d Elements successfully processed." % (countSuccess, countAll))
```

Sadly, there are a lot of files named exactly the same, even if they're different. So i can't overwrite existing files. I found a good solution here on stackoverflow and tried to solve this by adding incrementing numbers at the end of the filename.
All in all, it seems to function very well for most of my files, but there are some that do not work and i can't say why. Look at the following ones:

- Einladung und Tagesordnung zur ZVEI-Vorstandssitzung am 23  Juni 2010 - Protokoll der Vorstandssitzung vom 24  März 2010.msg
- Einladung und Tagesordnung zur ZVEI-Vorstandssitzung am 23  Juni 2010 - Protokoll der Vorstandssitzung vom 24  März 2010.msg
- Einladung und Tagesordnung zur ZVEI-Vorstandssitzung am 23  Juni 2010 - Protokoll der Vorstandssitzung vom 24  März 2010.msg

They should be all copied to this path: \FE0VM7775\Masseningest_P\Input\Portalraum-Ablage-Dais\G2 Sekretariat\Verbände_Vereine_Unis\ZVEI\ZVEI_2010\ZVEI_Vorstandssitzung_10032324.

All paths are correctly written and assigned to my dictionary. After copying, there is just one file in the destination - that means he overwrites it with every step in my loop, but why?

PS: This is what happens in winapi_path(), it solves my problem with copy errors, caused by too long paths. If Windows has a problem with the copied file does not matter for me, that it got copied is the only important thing:

```
def winapi_path(dos_path, encoding=None):
if (not isinstance(dos_path, str) and 
    encoding is not None):
    dos_path = dos_path.decode(encoding)
path = os.path.abspath(dos_path)
if path.startswith(u"\\\\"):
    return u"\\\\?\\UNC\\" + path[2:]
return u"\\\\?\\" + path
```

Comment: Can you please provide a part of the output of the program? What name does the file which is actually saved have?

Comment: Successfully copied \\FE02FS23\c_cch_austausch$\050_NN\Documents_G2 Kopie\Test\Einladung und Tagesordnung zur ZVEI-Vorstandssitzung am 23  Juni 2010 - Protokoll der Vorstandssitzung vom 24  März 2010.msg
to 
\\FE0VM7775\Masseningest_P\Input\Portalraum-Ablage-Dais\G2 Sekretariat\Verbände_Vereine_Unis\ZVEI\ZVEI_2010\ZVEI_Vorstandssitzung_10032324\Einladung und Tagesordnung zur ZVEI-Vorstandssitzung am 23  Juni 2010 - Protokoll der Vorstandssitzung vom 24  März 2010_mig.msg

...and this happens three times.